# QPrinter::Invalid metric command

Tags: qt, qwidget, qprinter

We are able to export/print preview on some machine using QPrinter command. But some we can not see the preview.

In the debug view getting below errors:

QPrinter::Invalid metric command
QWidget::render: cannot render with inactive painter

printsupport dll is copied to the appropriate loacation i.e. AppPath\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll

someone have any idea.Thanks.

Comment: did that use to work for you before and now it stopped? please provide the code you are using

Comment: It is working on some system but not on others.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
painter.scale(1.01, 1.01);
```

or

```
painter.scale(0.99, 0.99);
```

I do not know why but it works with my app.I do not really need to scale(), but without it, the same error occurs.
PS: [QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321889/qpainterbegin-paint-device-returned-engine-0-type-2)
Here is another example of this error.