# QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I'm trying to print Qtablewidget but it just print a blank page and application output show

```
QPrinter::metric: Invalid metric command
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QWidget::render: Cannot render with an inactive painter
```

print function

```
void MainWindow::on_btPrint_clicked(){
  QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
  QPrintDialog printer_dialog(&printer, this);
  if (printer_dialog.exec() == QDialog::Rejected) return;
  QPainter painter(&printer);
  ui->table_log->render(&painter);
}
```

[image: log table]

Comment: Is the variable `printer` [valid](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#isValid)?

Comment: printer.isValid() is true

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by set painter.scale

```
double xscale = printer.pageRect().width()/double(ui->table_log->width());
double yscale = printer.pageRect().height()/double(ui->table_log->height());
double scale = qMin(xscale, yscale);
painter.scale(scale, scale);
```

[Printing Widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtprintsupport-index.html)